# AndroidPlot invisible markers

Tags: android, marker, points, androidplot

I am adding real time data to an XY Plot. How can I remove the graph's dots/markers or make them invisible? I cannot find the according method in the java doc.

```
mSimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().setDrawMarkersEnabled(false);
```

is not working for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different options.

```
//Sets all grid lines to transparent
mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

//Sets only the domain lines to transparent
mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getGridDomainLinePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

//Sets only the range lines to transparent
mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getGridRangeLinePaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

And of course you can set the grid lines to any color this way, not just transparent.

I hope this helps.

Comment: as of mid 2014 this methods does not exist in the android plot 0.6.1 version of the jar. refer the below answer

Answer (score 3):

In my case the first method doen't exist in the libraries, and the second and the third are changed like this:

getDomainGridLinePaint();

and not

getGridDomainLinePaint();

But yes, it works. After setcontentview and before addseries in your activity onCreae method